# after_stat(count) not working as expected to create error bars in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to figure out how to add just simple error bars to a basic bar chart by using after_stat(count). My understanding is that when you use geom_bar and only specify an x value it stores the y axis (count) to after_stat(count). So I am just trying to add error bars that are +/- 3 from the count of each bar.

I have tried many variations of the following code but keep getting the error that after_stat(count) - 3 is ! non-numeric argument to binary operator. My understanding of this is that after_stat(count) is not being recognized as an integer or number but am unsure where these values are being stored in such a format I can plug them in here.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = drv, fill = class)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = after_stat(count) - 3, ymax = after_stat(count) + 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

`geom_bar` does calculate the count stat for you, but `geom_errorbar` does not. From the `?geom_errorbar` help page, you can see the default `stat=` is "identity". If you want it also to use the "count" stat like `geom_bar`, you'd have to specify that. For example

```
plot(mpg, aes(x = drv, fill = class)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
  geom_errorbar(stat="count", aes(ymin = after_stat(count) - 3, ymax = after_stat(count) + 3), position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))
```

Generally speaking, calculated values are not shared across layers. Note that we also had to include the same `position=` properties to get get the bars to line up with each of the same groups.
[image]

Comment: I feel so silly spending hours on this. thank you so much for the quick and succinct reply!